# How to provide a "hierarchical" URI scheme?

Tags: spring, rest, uri

For a project I'm working on, I'm looking for Spring annotations and other magic to provide me with this:

Suppose I have two REST Repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="/customers")
public interface CustomerRepository implements PagingAndSortRepository {
}

@RepositoryRestResource(path="???")
public interface OrderRepository implements PagingAndSortRepository {
}
```

Assume `Orders` is a sub-resource of `Customers`, meaning that a `Customer`can have multiple `Orders` (1-N).

Here's my question: I'd like `Orders` to be available under a URI ending in

```
...../customers/{customer_id}/orders/{order_id}
```

Is there a way to tell Spring that one is a sub-resource of the other AND that the path of an `Orders` resource should be relative to its owner `Customer`'s path?

I've been looking for sub-resources, relative paths, hierarchical URI schemes, etc., but came up with nothing. Guess I'm missing the correct search key?

Answer (score -1):

Why use a relative path? Use the absoulte path

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path="/customers/{customer_id}/orders/{order_id}")
```